# Material- UI icon disturbing the working of button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I click in the space around the icon,The button works correctly and the post get deleted.But when clicked on the icon `(<DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon />)`, the post doesn't get deleted.As the name of the button is props.id, when I log the name, it shows undefined, I also tried to give the same name to the icon, but still it doesn't work.

```
<button name={props.id} onClick={deletePost}><DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon /></button>
```

This is the `deletePost` function

```
function deletePost(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure to delete"))
        {
            let {name} = e.target;
            console.log(name);
            $.post("http://localhost:4000/delete" , {name})
            .done(res=>{
                setAll({value:res});
                console.log(allPosts);
            })
            .fail(e=>{console.log(e);})
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should wrap MUI Icon components with `<IconButton> </IconButton>` you can import that using `import {IconButton} from '@material-ui/core'`  so in your case it will be `<IconButton onClick={deletePost}><DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon /></IconButton>`

Edit: to get the correct value for the `name` property try:

```
 let name = e.target.getAttribute('name');
```

And by the way some attribute names aren't really appropriate to use in this condition and in some situations can maybe result in undesired behaviour (for example trying to set a name attribute on a `<th>` HTML element) you want a piece of data (a variable) which normally shouldn't even be done this way as you could just easily do `deletePost(e,props.id)` giving `props.id` as a parameter directly to your function.

Comment: name is still undefined

Comment: A. did you add a name property to the outer `IconButton` component?
B. where does `props.id` come from? have you made sure you got it right? and how do you log it? where does that relate to the issue which is being unable to trigger a button event by clicking on nested Icon which the solution I proposed in my answer solves.

Comment: Yes I put it right on the `IconButton` and also I have verified that props.id is actually right, I have logged it while the components are printing on screen, it is logging successfully, the problem is coming that when clicking on the button it is showing undefined. The button actually comes from mapping array which is fetched from node API. So everything is actually fine, but the problem is this button is not identifying it. When I use a simple html button without any icon or something, it is working fine.

Comment: where do you want to get the name? meaning where are you trying to use it? you should give more context its unclear what you want to achieve really. where is the code for your `deletePost` function?

Comment: name is the object.id(mongodb database) of the element which is being rendered. So by clicking on the button deletePost function will be called which will send a ajax post request to the server passing the  id(name in the button) of the post to be deleted.

Comment: and does it get it from state? it would be very helpful to post your `deletePost` function right now we have no idea what you're doing and how you log the name property.
and please read on how to post questions here because not only will it help the community identify your problem easier thus having an answer quicker but also it will help other developers that have followed similar footsteps and encountered a similar problem.

Comment: I have added the `deletePost` in the post above, and I will surely try to ask the question In a better way from next time.

Comment: I just edited my answer lmk if it works now

Comment: Previously on `console.log` it was undefined but now it is null still not working

Comment: did you recheck if the value in the scope of the button is not null? if it shows null that means its working and it can find the attribute but the value is null. you could also change `name` to `data-name` or something like that and get it the same way

Comment: Yes sir, I have tried changing `name` to `id` and other things but it still is same. And also tried to use simple html button, it is working perfectly with that.

Comment: try `data-name` you don't understand some attribute names aren't really appropriate to use in this condition you want a piece of DATA which normally shouldn't even be done this way (you could just easily do `deletePost(e,props.id)` giving `props.id` as a parameter directly to your function) you're trying to use a spoon to cut onions it might work but its not ideal

Comment: Yes sir, I didn't notice I can use props.id directly, Now its working, Thanks a lot. You are the best.

Comment: not a problem its my pleasure. a piece of advice I would give to you is try to read the documentation as much as possible especially the official documentation of React which is really easy to follow through and to brush up on the JavaScript language itself, it might be frustrating at first and it takes time because of the learning curve especially if you're a DIY person like me but I assure you its worth it. may the transistor gods be with you.

Comment: btw I will edit my answer to include my last comment to help others that might encounter the same problem

Comment: Ok Sir, do it and I'll read documentation for sure

Answer (score 0):

A bit more context may be needed for people to fully comprehend the issue. On first look I am wondering why you are wrapping a component in a button.

To create an outlined button with an icon using material-ui I'd stick to the material-ui documentation. So something along the lines of:

```
    <Button
    variant="outlined"
    color="secondary"
    className={classes.button}
    startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
    >
```

Where `<DeleteIcon/>` is an Icon you need to import from the material-ui library.